# How to limit numbers in edit box created in VS designer

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a project in Visual Studio. There is a dialog that I created in the designer view, which results in a bunch of IDs and properties in the .rc file. One of the controls is an edit box with ES_NUMBER set.

How can I set a min and max? All the answers I see are for programmatically created controls where one subclasses CEdit. Is it even possible to spawn a subclassed edit control when using the .rc?

Comment: The winapi is plain c language, the c++ tag is irrelevant here.

Comment: Similar problem as with `scanf` –  you can only check the range after it's entered, although it's possible to check digit by digit. This can be a nuisance for the user though, when using backspace etc and editing the content, to be forbidden an incomplete value.

Comment: The word 'subclass' seems to make C++ relevant.

Comment: @user3007190 Seems to, but doesn't actually. 'subclassing' a windows control is different than and in no way requires 'subclassing' a C++ class or using C++ at all in any way. How conceptually similar they are depends on how you have your head screwed on at the moment and from what angle and distance you are viewing things.

Comment: See [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/subclassing-overview) on MSDN.

Comment: Use **Superclassing**  (_GetClassInfo_) and **Custom Control** (not Edit) in the Designer with the new Edit class name (this was used in 16-bit and still works...)

Comment: @user3007190 Use [ES_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/edit-control-styles) style to allow only digits to be entered into the edit control. And show the valid rang to user or check the enter number after it's entered.

Answer (score 1):

Use a auto-buddy [Up-Down control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/up-down-control-reference).

Comment: AFAIK this only limits the min/max value for the Up-Down control, but doesn't affect manually entered numbers.

Comment: @zett42 That might be true but I'm guessing if you retrieve the value from the up-down control it will be within the limits.